# Webclient Request with Params

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest

I have a Windows Desktop application that needs to call a CGI script on a Remote Server.

The CGI Script looks like below

```
   RemoteCGIServer/Scripts/CGIScript.exe?UserName=****&GroupName=***&.......
```

When I run the follwing code, I get an exception

```
String url = "RemoteCGIServer/Scripts/CGIScript.exe?UserName=****&GroupName=***&......."
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] returnData = wc.DownloadData(creditNowURI);
sOutputXML = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(returnData);
```

The exception I get is

```
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. 
The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, 
and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Is there a way to add UserName and GroupName etc as Parameters?

Comment: I just found out that, the file from where I was reading the URL was missing http:// from infront of the URL. This was causing the issue. Adding the http:// fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a restriction in the Windows win32 api. The directory where you put your project is quite deep. You should put your project to other directory, closer to the root.

This link may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well the CGI is only 1 folder deep. So its not that deep. The URL string is 860 Chars long. That is the real problem. But if I take the URL and run it via a browser it runs fine.